# How to know in Talend if tMySQLInput will overwrite data?

Tags: talend

I have one already existing Talend Open Studio tMySQLInput component with some sql code inside it, in order to retrieve some joined columns linked to a tMySQLOuput component (pointing to an already existing MySQL table) with few records.

QUESTION: 
Will the "tMySQLInput" component overwrite the already existing table data that the tMySQLOutput component relates to? I mean is there an option to check in the tMySQLInput our output in order to say, overwrite each time this job is executed ?

Thank you all.

Comment: whjat do you mean by `our` in  following line `is there an option to check in the tMySQLInput our output in order to say, overwrite each time this job is executed ?`

Comment: From your question what I understood is that you have the same table from which you are taking the records, performing some joins and you are rewriting on the same table. Is it the case?

Comment: I meant to  wrote that WE HAVE THIS tMySQLInput (select code takes columns from 2 diff tables)  component that is connected to a tMySQLOutput component and so the goal is that when the job is ran it will insert the rows selected by the tMySQLInput in the table (a 3rd table we are talking here) indicated in the tMySQLOutput settings.This 3rd Table we are taling allready contains rows so i just wanted to make sure the execution of the job wont overwrite them, and the reason why i was "just asking" if perhaps there was some hidden checkbox in Talend i had to make sure was uncheck for example.

Comment: You want to use tMySQLInput and tMySQLOutput only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an option where in tMySQLOutput where you can specify what action you want to do to your table. Follow following steps:

1. Go to component tab of tMySQLOutput, it will open the basic settings of this component.
2. If you will look closer you will find **Action on table**. This is the action which you can perform on the table which is pointed by tMySQLOutput. It has options as **Default**, **Drop** and **Create Table** etc.
3. Then you have **Action on data**. These are the options which you can perform on the data like **Insert**, **Update** etc.

In your case I suppose you can choose Action on Table as Default and Action on Data as Insert. Default action would not do anything on the table and Insert option would insert the records at the end of table. But in case of Insert if you will have duplicate rows then job would stop the moment it will find any duplicate row.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to know. Thanks.                                                         And yes i only need these 2 ckmponents linked togeter and i don't think i need a tMap component from what i read in forums in my case.I don't know if this will work but before testing my hob i wanted to make sure it was not going to overwrite anything in our 3rd table.

Comment: You can test it and let me know.

Comment: You are welcome. A humble request - from next time try to be clear with the question, it will help people answer your query much faster.